# Kali linux openvpn working with GUI but not with the terminal

Tags: vpn, terminal, openvpn, kali-linux

I would like to use openvpn but using terminal only.
For this I've installed multiple network-manager packet :

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-pptp-gnome
network-manager-strongswan
network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

Then I went in NetWorkManger.conf and I changed the  :

```
[ifupdown] managed=false
```

to :

```
[ifupdown] managed=true
```

Then I proceed to restart the network-manager service and the networking service.

Then I did the following command :

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-de233-tcp80.ovpn
```

(I got the ovpn file [here](https://www.vpnbook.com/))

Wich answered an input that ended with :

```
Initialization Sequence Completed
```

But then when I tried to ping any website, it said that it couldn't find the target. As if it was offline.

I don't understand since when I use the GUI interface to set the VPN I have no problem at all. Am I missing something ?